# Get the R2/RMSE for each category of a dataset

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-squared, rms

This might be a dumb question !

I built a model and I'm satisfied enough with the model, given that I have a dataset with categorical variables I wanted to see the R2/RMSE for each of those categories, but I'm unsure on which set I should conduct this test should I use the training set for that ? My understanding is that the results would be too good because the model already "saw" the data I'm inputing.

So should I use the test set instead ?

Comment: You are optimizing the global loss, so not necessarily it'd be equally good withing groups, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy

Answer (score 0):

As Tim wrote, you have to keep in mind that the regression model you used optimized the global loss. Therefore for some group inside the performance may be poor.
Then, wanted to look at performance for each of these groups is the way to find ideas to get a better global performance.

As you train the model with the train set, you are going to use the test set to look at the performance of the model if you have the response. Otherwise, just perform a train/test split with the train set so that you get a validation set.

To recap :

- You have a train and test set with response : use the test set to look at performance for all the categories
- You have a train set with response and a test set without : extract from the train set a validation set (with a train/test split) and look at performance for all the categories on this new dataset.

Looking at performance with only *one shot* i.e with a train/test split may not give you the right information (since it depends a bit on the random). It may be better to look at performance with a cross-validation. Then you can output a table that look like this :

| Variable 1 | Variable 2 | R2 | RMSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 0.8 (+/- 0.1) | 200 (+/- 25) |
| A | B | 0.7 (+/- 0.1) | 250 (+/- 30) |
| B | A | 0.9 (+/- 0.1) | 150 (+/- 20) |
| C | A | 0.7 (+/- 0.2) | 230 (+/- 20) |

With a cross-validation you get a better overview of performance and robustness of the built model. One can look at [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) on implemented cross-validation technique. For your use case I suggest using the *K-fold* class.

Answer (score 0):

For RMSE, the answer is straightforward: calculate RMSE on the holdout observations for each group. This could lead to insights like, "We are good at predicting this in general, but we get closer predictions when we predict for dogs than we do for wolves." You calculate on the holdout set because, as you point out, performance calculations on the training data are biased high, perhaps immensely so.

For $R^2$, it is not clear what to do, and it depends on what you want to learn. If you want to learn how your model predictions are compared to always predicting the mean of the group, do your calculations with such a $\bar y$. If you want to know about always predicting the overall mean, use that $\bar y$.

$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$